# How to prove $ (B \cap C) \cup A = B \cap (C \cup A) \rightarrow A \subseteq B $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be any sets. Then
>   $$ (B \cap C) \cup A = B \cap (C  \cup A) \rightarrow A \subseteq B  $$

Comment: Drawing a picture is always a good way to start. See which regions belongs to one and not the other. If you equate them, some particular region(s) will get forced to be inside of others.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in A$, for the adition property
$$x\in A \rightarrow x \in A \lor x\in(B \cup C) $$
$\rightarrow$For hypothesis:
$$x\in B \land x\in (A \cup C)$$
$\rightarrow$For logic simplification
$$x \in B$$
$(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \rightarrow x\in A \subseteq B \blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

All elements of A are in LHS. And since LHS=RHS, all those elements should also be in B. So A is a subset of B.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not, so take $x\in A$ such that  $x \notin B$.
So clearly $x \in (B \cap C) \cup A$ because $x$ is in $A$, but $x \notin B \cap (C  \cup A)$ because $x$ is not in $B$. So we have
$$
(B \cap C) \cup A \neq B \cap (C  \cup A)
$$

Comment: Can you use algebra of classes for show more clearly your proof?

Comment: -1 for formulating this as a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @testpilot, had you wanted a solution using the algebra of classes, you definitely should have made that more clear in the question, and definitely not have just tagged this as "elementary set theory."